# Project Database My SQL and Java, JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wrapper

Hi Everyone I just need everyones help since I'll be working on a project here

my project is I have to create a database, well a simple one Using Open office base(for the tables and MySQL queries) and Java(for the UI , Wrapper, user Input, and interaction with the database) but the thing is I don't know where to start is it possible to link Java and Open office database?, we haven't been thought about this, but I want to start in advance any suggestions, guides or tutorials, can any guide me briefly or give me an idea or good approach to it? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Office Base seems to have a [pretty good docset](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Database#Connecting).

Did you try the [Connect MySQL and Base](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQLandBase)?

Comment: uhmm Thanks, but what are the codes? or where can I get ideas from? like the UI interacting with the database?